# PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)

Tags: wine, playonlinux

When I run PlayOnLinux gives me this message:

> PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)
>
> You should install it to use PlayOnLinux

What should I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to install wine & to do so ,open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

thats it.

Comment: what's the matter with common sense.

Comment: you may need to do 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa' first. Also could use 'sudo apt-get install wine1.7' for the latest version. Finally could do an 'apt-get update'.

Comment: @user204653 One of the reasons why I think it's a little confusing is because you can "install wine" from inside of the application as well. It's a UX sort of thing that is a little confusing.

Comment: @Raja Common sense?  That gets you an obsolete version of wine (and did back in 2013, too).  Installing playonlinux will _by default_ install wine-development -- and *that* doesn't appear to install an alternatives option for wine!

Comment: Above comments were deleted and if you want me to remind something that happened 3 years ago... i would say something.