# How to install wine through playonlinux in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

I have been trying to install `wine` but I encountered issues like

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.1~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and got solutions from [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) and [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) but nothing solved it.

So I read somewhere that you can [install wine through `playonlinux`](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27246) from. So I installed `wine` using [this reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux). However, I am unable to figure out how to install `wine` from `playonlinux`.

So I found it from [PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378418/playonlinux-cannot-find-wine-from-wine) and ran

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

but I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to resolve?

UPDATES  -

@Norbert

[playonlinux-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/138MM.png)

@ David

[playonlinux-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgDId.png)

---

The output of the commands is below:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

...

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

...

```
$ apt-cache policy "$(dpkg -S "$(which wine)" | cut -d : -f 1)"
...
N: unable to locate package

$ wine --version
...
wine: command not found
```

Comment: It is unclear what you exactly did. Please add output of the `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `apt-cache policy \`dpkg -S $(which wine)\`
`, `wine --version`.

Comment: @N0rbert: `apt-cache policy "$(dpkg -S "$(which wine)" | cut -d : -f 1)"` would be better.

Comment: Thanks Norbert and david, i have added the screenshots of the output of your commands

Comment: Still unclear. @DavidFoerster, thank you for idea. Techdive, please add the information to your question (copy and paste commands exactly).

Comment: If there's no `wine` executable could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy wine\*`? And could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.